# I'd like to see the whole thread when editing my question or answer

Tags: feature-request, edits

Often when editing a question or answer, I would like to make reference to other answers or the question while I make the edits.  Today, when you go into edit mode, only the item under edit is visible.

I think it would be helpful to be able to see the whole question and answers all together as context when performing an edit.

Comment: Right-click "edit" and open in a new tab/window. Problem solved?

Comment: Also you can reference the question when editing an answer (it's at the top in a small, but re-sizable panel)

Comment: @Jon Seigel A new tab doesn't quite accomplish what I want to do of seeing both my edits and the other entries simultaneously.

Comment: @Alconja I'm not finding what you are referring to.

Comment: @WilliamKF You don't see the question right above the answer edit box? There's a grey bar with lines in the middle just underneath it that you can drag to resize it

Comment: @Michael Mrozek It appears that is only visible when editing an answer, not the original question.  I wish to see the other answers as I edit the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the entire question by expanding the question pane in the edit window.

[image: Expand the question pane.]

As for other answers, you'll need to edit your answer in another tab or window, as mentioned in the comments.  I don't see much difference between switching between tabs and scrolling up and down, since *all* the information can't be visible on my screen either way.  If you have two monitors, opening the editor in a separate window is definitely the best solution.

Comment: It would be nice to have the same question pane when editing the question itself.

Comment: @WilliamKF: I usually keep one eye on the preview section below the editor pane.  I know there are a couple of issues with the MarkDown not rendering *exactly* right in the preview, but those are few and I hardly ever see them in my posts.

Comment: The preview pane is like that pane only vastly superior since it reflects changes; I don't know why you'd want a frozen snapshot of the old question when you have that

Comment: When I am editing the question, I often wish to refer to the posted answers and comments which may ask the question be refined in a particular fashion that I wish to review as I edit the question.